# Is there a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N^2$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Is there a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N^2$?

If I can show $\mathbb N^2$ is equipotent to $\mathbb N$, I can show that $\mathbb Q$ is countable. Please help. Thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is easier to write an answer than to find one of its several occurrences on this site.

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then there exist uniquely determined positive integers $u$ and $v$ such that $n=2^{u-1}(2v-1)$. This is because every positive integer $n$ can be written in one and only one way as a power of $2$ (possibly $2^0$) and an odd number.

Define $g$ by $g(n)=(u,v)$. Then $g$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^2$.

For a different bijection, search for the *Cantor Pairing Function*.

Comment: Indeed the first duplicate I found has essentially the same answer by you!

Comment: It might be nice to learn some searching secrets. I did remember answering the question, but *finding* is another matter.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You can search for [`user:me is:answer cantor pairing`](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6312+is%3Aanswer+cantor+pairing) to boil it down to (currently) seven candidates

Comment: How exactly do you write 8 with this?

Comment: This seems wrong. let n = 2^m. Then 2^(m-u+1)=2v-1 which is impossible if v is a positive integer

Answer (score 13):

Here is a non constructive proof.

Of course, there is an injection of $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Now consider the map
$$
(x,y)\longmapsto 2^x\cdot 3^y
$$
By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, this is an injection of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{N}$.

By [Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem), there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Edit: I added this answer because the only constructive proof I knew was the zigzag along the diagonals, which I find slightly tedious to write down. But thanks to Andre Nicolas, now I know a straightforward and easy-to-write-down bijection. Which is actually a little step away from the injection I use above.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there exists a quadratic bijection.

See [this](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/cantorpairing.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Imagine starting at $(1,1)$ and then zig-zagging diagonally across the quadrant. I'll leave you to formulate it.

Hint: for every natural number $>1$ there's a set of elements of $\mathbb{N}^2$ that add up to that number. For $2$, there's $(1,1)$. For $3$, there's $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$...

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to find a way to "count" the things in $\mathbb N^2$ in a manner that gets you to any pair $(a,b)$ in some finite time. Notice that "counting" something is essentially finding this bijection - there is a "first" pair, and a "second pair" and so on.

There are many ways to do this, but most of them come down to ordering the set $\mathbb N^2$ in some meaningful way.

Hint: There are countably many diagonals, i.e. there is a "first diagonal" a "second diagonal" and so on. Does this work?